# Implementing an abstract method with return type of Class<T1<T2>>

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract test class that has two type parameters. I need to make an instance of one of the types at some point, so I defined an abstract method to get the required class.

`I doc = getInputDocumentClass().newInstance();`

How can I implement the abstract method `Class<T1<T2>> getInputDocumentClass()` in a concrete subclasses?

To return the class literal for T1 is not enough:

```
@Override
public Class<T1<T2>> getInputDocumentClass() {
    return T1.class;
}

cannot convert from Class<T1> to Class<T1<T2>>
```

There are no parameterized class literals due to type erasure.

So how can I satisfy the compiler in this case?

Comment: are you literally referring to the `getClass()` method defined by Java's Object class or some generic `getSomeClass()` method? The `getClass()` method cannot be overwritten, whereas any other method can be solved by casting. An some more code would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, it's one of the messy cases. Bleah.

Comment: @ArtB No, just my own method. I'll edit the question to show my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Class<List<Integer>> getInputDocumentClass() {
    return (Class)List.class;
}
```